# Inherited Usercontrol component usage?

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, user-controls

I have a question about usercontrol components. I can't find a way to describe it, so I'll tell you what I have and what is the problem.

My project has to have multiple user controls, which can be dragged and resized. There is a main user control UC, which has two pictureBoxes in two corners of it. One for resize function, and one for drag function.

[image: Picture1]

Basically, when I create a new userControl, it has those pictureboxes, because the program must have an option to drag them all, no matter how many userControls are created.

This is how it looks, if 3 iherited usercontrols are created:

[image]

---

Now the problem:

1. User control class doesn't see panels&stuff on the form. I googled it a bit and stumbled upon custom events, but I don't understand them one bit.
2. How can I tell which user control I must drag if there are 3 pictureboxes with the same name?

I'm stuck here, any help appreciated.

*Developer in training*

**sorry for link-pictures, but I have only 5 reputation. Adding images requires 10 reputation...**

Comment: You question is vague. Do you want to know "How to implement resizing and moving in the UserControl"? It doesn't matter if you have 1 or 3 controls on the form. If you implement the resize and move (in the user control), it works for all.

Comment: The thing is that I can't implement it, because when I try to write a drag event, it does not see the panel in the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Every control has [`Left`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.left.aspx), [`Top`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.top.aspx), [`Width`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.width.aspx) and [`Height`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.height.aspx) properties that control the placement and size of the control inside its containers.

You don't need to see the `Panel`, however if you need to, you can access the [`Parent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent.aspx) property of the control.